# How to create annotations from a Firebase Cloud server in Xcode 12- Swift 5

Tags: swift, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, mapkit, mkannotation

Here is the code I use. I have saved from previous code a sorted listed of pharmacies in my database! In the code I want to retrieve that array, and then create a fore loop in this array (The list, in addition to being sorted, shows the pharmacies that are closer than specific distance to the user, but that's irrelevant), to retrieve the latitude and longitude of the pharmacies that I have save on a different collection. I use the for loop (for pharmacy in closestpharmacyname), and then do a query in my database in which the document I use is pharmacy(From the For Loop)! Everything works fine until the for loop! I can't even print anything! It just doesn't work ! Can you please help me??

```
class Home: UIViewController, CLLocationManagerDelegate {


@IBOutlet var MapView: MKMapView!

@IBAction func SwitchfromMapType(_ sender: Any) {
    if (sender as AnyObject).selectedSegmentIndex == 0{

        MapView.mapType = MKMapType.standard
        }
    else if (sender as AnyObject).selectedSegmentIndex == 1{

            MapView.mapType = MKMapType.satellite
        }}
@IBAction func FindNearestPharmacies(_ sender: Any) {
    
    
    let docRef1 = db.collection("closestpharmacies").document(user!.uid)

    docRef1.getDocument(source: .cache) { (document, error) in
        if let document  = document {
            let closestpharmacyname = document.get("ClosestPharmacies") as! Array<Any>
            
            print("Closest Pharmacies:",closestpharmacyname)
        

            for pharmacy in closestpharmacyname{
                print(pharmacy)
                let docref2 = db.collection("Pharmacies").document(pharmacy as! String)
                print("Pharmacy: ", pharmacy)
                docref2.getDocument(source: .cache) { (document, error) in
                    if let document  = document {
                        let pharmacylatitude = document.get("latitude") as! Double
                        let pharmacylongitude = document.get("longitude") as! Double
                        print(pharmacylatitude, pharmacylongitude)
                            
                        let pharmacyannotation = MKPointAnnotation()
                        pharmacyannotation.coordinate = CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: pharmacylatitude, longitude: pharmacylongitude)
                        pharmacyannotation.title = pharmacy as! String
                        self.MapView.addAnnotation(pharmacyannotation)
                    } else{
                        print("Document Does not exist")
                    }
            
            
    
                }}}}}



override func viewDidLoad() {
super.viewDidLoad()
    let docRef = db.collection("users").document(user!.uid)

    docRef.getDocument(source: .cache) { (document, error) in
        if let document  = document {
            let userlat = document.get("latitude") as! Double
            let userlong = document.get("longitude") as! Double
        
            let annotation = MKPointAnnotation()
            annotation.coordinate = CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: userlat , longitude: userlong )
            annotation.title = "Your Location"
            
            print(userlat,userlong)
            
            self.MapView.addAnnotation(annotation)
    
        } else {
            print("Document does not exist")
        }
    }}}
```

Comment: You should explain further why your code isn't doing what you want. Are you getting any error? In this case you could post the traceback.

Comment: @Ilompalles It simply doesn't execute! No errors, not nothing! I think it has to do with the document query and maybe it isn't a string, the 'let docref2 = db.collection("Pharmacies").document(pharmacy as! String)'